# Laravel read and write connection not in sync

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using read and write MySQL connection setup in my Laravel 5.2 app:

```
'mysql' => [
    'write' => ['host' => env('DB_HOST_WRITE', 'localhost'),],
    'read'  => ['host' => env('DB_HOST_READ', 'localhost'),],
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null
]
```

The website runs on multiple servers, using a load balancer.

Now, in the app, there are cases of read and write operations done one after another, e.g.

1. insert new records into the database
2. select some of the newly inserted records

With the current connection setup, it can happen that the select will return nothing, even if the records were inserted correctly.

What can be the reasons for this?

Comment: Okay, how many databases nodes you use, what algorithm or software you use for sync..
Databases sync may not be immediate because of the network latency, processing delays or deliberately.

Comment: We've got 2 nodes. As for software, we use Amazon Aurora. How do I make sure we've got stable sync?

Comment: Well, I am not expert in Aurora but according to their website there is about latency of 100 ms for replication.. 
try to insert delay between the insertion and the selection operations about 200 ms and see if this solves it..
Then you have to dig deeper in Aurora itself

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Also, I suppose that another option is to manually use the same connection for those specific write-read situations.

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5.5 I've done a PR for this that introduces a "sticky" option.

It means your application will use the "read" connection whenever possible, but if you do a "write", then any subsequent "reads" on the same request cycle will also come from the write connection.

This ensures data integrity.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/20445

Comment: Looks promising. I will be testing this as soon as we upgrade to 5.5. Thanks for the valuable PR and letting us know here.

Comment: Thanks. The reason this is a config option and not default is just be cafeful if you do a small "write" followed by a long large "read". It means the large read will be on your write database. It's a balancing act - and should be ok in most situations. But just be mindful of it.

Comment: That is a fantastic idea.

Comment: Beware this can cause [performance issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/20445#issuecomment-355335010) if not used carefully for the specific use case you desire

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Laravel specific problem. This is called master slave replication lag.

There are multiple prevention techniques but only one technique that "cures" the problem

**First the Cures: Avoid read write combos**:

Don't perform a select operation immediately after an insert (read-write combo). This might sound crazy at first, but if you can avoid it, avoid it!

If you cant do this but you can identify where the read-write combos would happen in your code, just use the master for both read and write ops

**Prevention Techniques (if cure is not possible)**

1. Enable [slave compressed protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#sysvar_slave_compressed_protocol)
2. Disable binary logging on slave
3. Optimize mysql queries (e.g. add indexes, etc.)
4. Other ways: manual sleep between insert and select queries, wrapping both inserts and selects in a single transaction (again would be done using the master connection while slave is free)

Comment: Using master for both is the only real way forward. Polling on the slaves introduces more read traffic than it's worth and relying on the prevention techniques might cause more problems because the reads replicas won't always be fast enough, just sometimes. Debugging problems will be horrific if there is any multi-step database work done.